# Use jquery to copy form from lightbox window back to parent page

Tags: jquery

I have built a form to collect data from users. Part of the form features a Jquery lightbox to capture additional data. I then want to copy that form back into the parent page. I have tried using the .html() function to copy the form from the lightbox and pass it back to the parent page. The problem though is that it doesn't copy the values that the user has entered into the lightbox form.

Is there an alternative method I can use that will return both the form html and the entered data?

Comment: iterate over the inputs and save them into a json, or an array ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('form').serialize();` it will return data that contains form.